# Is there a way of obtaining all library objects within an instance of JS?

Tags: javascript

Is there a method in which I can iterate through all objects that exist within an instance of JavaScript, regardless of the JavaScript engine that is being used?  I'm not interested in iterating through the DOM of a web page.  What I want to know is if there is a way that I can iterate through all standard library objects (Array, Math, Date, etc.) as well as any additional libraries that may be specific to various browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No... and yes.  The `window` object is the global object in a browser.  It contains all the native members of the global scope, plus all the functions and properties provided for the DOM.

Native objects like Math, Array and Date are non-enumerable members of the global object, which means you can't iterate over them using a `for...in` loop.  That covers the "no" part — there's no way of obtaining these objects through iteration in many browsers.

However, with ECMAScript 5th Edition implementations (IE 9, Chrome 7, Firefox 4) you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` to get an array of property names for a specific object.  For instance,

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window));
```

Will give you a list of all the members of the global `window` object, including Math, Array, Date, etc.

Comment: Pointing the obvious here, but to refer to the global object use `this` in global scope (since outside the context of a browser there is no `window`)